# pic ccs c 16f84a.h

Tags: microcontroller, c, pic-ccs

[image]

I didn't find a solution to this error.
I already tried every thought I had. I searched a lot on the net and didn't find a thing.
Generally the answer is to add a bracket `{`, but it does not seem to be the case here.

program:

```
#include <16f84a.h>
#use delay (clock=4000000)
void main() 
{
    set_tris_b(0x00);
    set_tris_a(0xFF);

    while (true)
    { 
        if ((input(pin_A0))==0)
        {
            {
                output_high(pin_B0);
                output_high(pin_B2);
                output_high(pin_B4);
                output_high(pin_B6);
                output_low(pin_B1);
                output_low(pin_B3);
                output_low(pin_B5);
                output_low(pin_B7);
                delay_ms(1000);
                output_high(pin_B1);
                output_high(pin_B3);
                output_high(pin_B5);
                output_high(pin_B7);
                output_low(pin_B0);
                output_low(pin_B2);
                output_low(pin_B4);
                output_low(pin_B6);
                delay_ms(1000);
            }
        else if ((input(pin_A1))==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                        output_high(pin_B0);
                        output_high(pin_B2);
                        output_high(pin_B4);
                        output_high(pin_B6);
                        output_low(pin_B1);
                        output_low(pin_B3);
                        output_low(pin_B5);
                        output_low(pin_B7);
                        delay_ms(1000);           
                        output_low(pin_B0);
                        output_low(pin_B2);
                        output_low(pin_B4);
                        output_low(pin_B6);
                        delay_ms(1000);
                    }
                }
            }   
        }   
    }
```

Comment: My gut feeling is that you have an unmatched parenthesis, or a bracket, or a curly brace... somewhere.  The compiler can't figure out a more detailed diagnosis, that's why you get a generic "build failed" error.

Comment: If you have trouble finding errors, reduce the complexity and comment out sections of your code and get to a point that works. Then slowly add sections back in until it breaks. Have good troubleshooting skills.

Answer (score 2):

If you format your code sensibly you'll see that immediately after your

```
 if ((input(pin_A0))==0)
```

on line 11 you have 2 { on lines 12 & 13 when you should only have 1

Answer (score 0):

You are using C, not C++, so I don't think you should be declaring the variable 'i' inside the for loop. There may be a compiler switch that allows this, I'm not that familiar with CCS.

Try declaring 'int i;' just inside the first curly bracket for main(){
and change the for loop to:

> for(i=0;i<10;i++)

Comment: "You are using C, not C++, so I don't think you should be declaring the variable 'i' inside the for loop" - Hi, I'm not a "language lawyer" but FYI that feature was added to C99, as explained in the [C99 Rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf): "A new feature of C99: C89 requires all declarations in a block to occur before any statements. On the other hand, many languages similar to C (such as Algol 68 and C++) permit declarations and statements to be mixed in an arbitrary manner. This feature has been found to be useful and has been added to C99."

Comment: C language implementations for limited 8-bit Harvard-architecture processors typically don't implement the latest features. Do you know that the OP's version of CCS C (or any version) implements this feature? Some versions apparently do not.

Comment: Completely agree - many embedded-focussed compilers don't support recent C language features. I haven't used any recent versions of CCS. Since you seemed to be comparing C++ vs. C, the reason for my earlier comment was just to explain to readers who may interpret your answer as "C does not support that feature, but C++ does" that C compilers which support C99, not only C++, can support that language feature. That's all :-)

Comment: @SamGibson fair enough!